# Spring Boot Cache TTL

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, abstraction

I want to use Spring Boot Cache Abstraction to cache some data (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

I'm open to using any of the providers that are available.

The main thing I need is this: I want to be able to set object level TTL, not just global cache level TTL.

E.g. for each object I store in my cache, I want to **specify a custom TTL for the object based on some property of that object**.

I know that to set up something like this, it must be done directly through the cache provider; but I have not been able to find examples of my use case - only found use cases where global TTL was being set. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with redis, you can take a look at [JetCache](https://github.com/alibaba/jetcache):

`@Cached(expire = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
User getUserById(long userId);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the features of the different cache implementations available for Spring boot.

Supporting a variable expiry based on the entry value, has implications on the internals of the cache implementation and its performance. With variable expiry you need typically a O(log n) data structure. For example, Guava and Caffeine do not support it. EHCache does support it, see the [Documentation about expiry](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/expiry.html).

The requested functionality is "beyond" the Spring abstraction, which means, you need to produce code for one specific cache implementation.